# In selenium Anchor tag onclick function not working?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I have javascript onclick as:

```
<a href="#" id="download" onclick="Exceldownload('sites')">
    <i class="fa fa-download card-down-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

In selenium I added like this:

```
public void x() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@onclick='Exceldownload("sites")']")).click();
}
```

But I am getting error as element is not clickable.

Comment: You need to verify first, if other element overlay on it..in this case you should wait until element to be clickable..

Comment: Is it possible to call function directly instead of anchor tag id?

Comment: Yes, but this is not a right behavior of testing. you need to identify the actual problem for click..

Answer (score 2):

Possibilities

1. Duplicate web element with same xpath in the page.
2. Element may be in frame. You need to switch to frame
3. Trying to access the web element before page is loading.Give some wait time.

If everything is correct try by clicking through java script click as shown in snippet.

```html
WebElement element =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@onclick='Exceldownload("sites")']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: it is showing error as "a[@onclick='Exceldownload("sites")']" is not valid  Xpath expression

Comment: remove double quotes from "sites" and make it 'sites'. or
WebElement element =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@onclick='Exceldownload("+"sites"+")']"));

Answer (score 2):

> element is not clickable

This issue can have multiple reasons as below:

- Maybe some other element like a loading image overlays the element and disappears after the element is fully loaded. Then you should wait until the element is clickable:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
      ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("download"))).click();
  ```
- Maybe there are multiple elements present with the same locator, and unfortunately you're locating a hidden element which is present on the page but not clickable. Then you need to use a unique locator.
- Maybe this occurred due to a designing problem. It might be possible some other element overlays the element and is receiving the click event. Then you can use `JavascriptExecutor` as an alternative solution:

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
      "arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.id("download")));
  ```

Comment: Element not clickable Error